# Issue aligning buttons on the DOM in Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, dom-manipulation

Am using Datatables to display some data on tables on the Dom. It works fine except that at the top I am trying to position the DOM which has **buttons, dropdown page selection** list and **search box** which aint aligning properly.  Am using Bootstrap 4. I have used this link to align the DOM but aint working: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

**My code**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                lengthChange: true,
                buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'],
                dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'f>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
            });
        });
```

**Screenshot of the DOM on my computer while using the code above**
[image: Screenshot of the Jquery Datatable DOM]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting expected output

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Duly noted,, have added a screenshot of the DOM... trying to make them to be aligned properly

Comment: I'm not asking for a picture, please recreate your problem in a website like jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can place the relevant elements in the bootstrap panel.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"panel panel-default"<"panel-heading"<"row"<"col-md-6"l><"col-md-6 text-right"f>>>t<"panel-footer"<"row"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6 text-right"p>>>>'
}); });
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a62hqqf9/